# Opencart v1.5.6.4 - PHP Fatal error: 'Function name must be a string'

Tags: php, opencart, php-7, fatal-error

I am in a process to make Opencart v1.5.6.4 compatible with PHP 7. I stumble upon a error something like below.

```
PHP Fatal error: 'Function name must be a string' 

public function notify(sfEvent $event){
     foreach ($this->getListeners($event->getName()) as $listener){
     ------->$listener[0]->$listener[1]($event);
     }
     return $event;
}
```

How can I solve this issue for PHP 7?
I have indicated a line by arrow which is throwing an error.

Comment: Do a var dump on `$listener` - does it have 2 parameters?

Comment: @CountKyle Yes. I did. But it is hanging up my system.